# Reopening a Disposed form declared with events. VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dialog

I have a dialog form which is a bar code scanner handler form that has events on the form it was called from, done like this:

```
Public Class FRMCheckout

     Dim WithEvents Batch_Scanner_Dialog As New CheckoutBatchScanner

     Private Sub Recieve_Scaned_Object(Scan_Object As tructures.ScanDetails) Handles Batch_Scanner_Dialog.Scanned_Item
         '.....Do Stuff'
     End Sub

     Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         Batch_Scanner_Dialog.Show()
     End Sub

End Class
```

The Batch_Scanner_Dialog is closed with just the regular old Close.Me which opbviously disposes itself.

The problem being if you wish to open the dialog again, an accessing a disposed object exception is thrown.

Locally Declaring the Dialog will not work, because it has events, so how could I fix this issue? Calling a new instance of the dialog is fine, just the original Events should be on the calling form. (They vary depending on the form the dialog is called form)

(Note: I need to use .show not .showdialog to continue to run code on the original form.)

Comment: I suspect AddHandler is the solution....

Comment: Another option is to call `ShowDialog`.  The form will not automatically be disposed when it is closed after `ShowDialog`

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem was solved with:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    If Batch_Scanner_Dialog.IsDisposed Then
        Dim Batch_Scanner_Dialog As New CheckoutBatchScanner
        AddHandler Batch_Scanner_Dialog.Scanned_Item, AddressOf Recieve_Scaned_Object
        Batch_Scanner_Dialog.Show()
    Else
        Batch_Scanner_Dialog.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```